# Remote Desktop with custom parameter

Tags: windows, command-line, remote-desktop, parameters

is there any way way to open the mstsc (remote desktop connection) with a custom parameter I initialized and then read it on the remote computer via command prompt?

I need to create batch file that will, open remote desktop and then automatically open another batch file that continues the process on the remote system if the parameter is initialized.

Comment: Why not just create a script which executes on logon on the remote machine??

Comment: Because I don't want that the script will starts in every logon...

Comment: As a work around, *maybe* you create a new user for the remote machine which is only used in the instance you want this behaviour... So the user becomes the parameter

Comment: @inon: A possible workaround might be to have a file on the client machine's hard drive that could be read through the appropriate path, e.g. *\\tsclient\C\Temp\File.txt* by your batch file (*tsclient* resolves to the connecting machine and gives access to its disk drives if you choose to make them available when you connect)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a slightly different approach. Take a look at the [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) utility. PsExec can run BATCH scripts on remote machines. So in your local BATCH script you would launch mstsc asynchronously, optionally wait a few seconds, then call PsExec to execute your second script remotely.

Answer (score 0):

[The comment of @James](https://superuser.com/questions/666919/remote-desktop-with-custom-parameter?noredirect=1#comment842715_666919), is the best answer for me:

> A possible workaround might be to have a file on the client machine's
>   hard drive that could be read through the appropriate path, e.g.
>   \tsclient\C\Temp\File.txt by your batch file (tsclient resolves to
>   the connecting machine and gives access to its disk drives if you
>   choose to make them available when you connect)

Thanks!